# Bucky Robert's first task, validating password with isupper(), isdigit(), and the containment of a '$' character

Tags: c

Ok so I have been watching Bucky Robert's tutorials on C programming and the first task he gives the viewers is to make a program that checks if a password has at least one upper case character, one digit, and one dollar sign.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int upper = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    int dollar = 0;

    char password[16];

    int loop = 1;

    while(loop == 1){

        printf("Enter your password: ");
        scanf(" %s", password);

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i <= 16; i++){
            printf(" %c", password[i]);

            if(isupper(password[i])){
                upper = 1;
                printf("\t is upper");
            }

            if(isdigit(password[i])){
                digit = 1;
                printf("\t is digit");
            }

            if(password[i] == '$'){
                dollar = 1;
                printf("\t is dollar");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        if((upper == 1) && (digit == 1) && (dollar == 1)){
            printf("Your password is valid\n");
            loop = 0;
        } else {
            printf("Your password is invalid\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program prints this in the console after an input of 'P4sswoRd':

```
 Enter your password: P4sswoRd
 P       is upper
 4       is digit
 s
 s
 w
 o
 R       is upper
 d

 ╨

 @

 ö
  
 `
 $       is dollar
 Your password is valid
```

None of the passwords i entered contain the '$' character yet the program still finds a way to detect it. The reason it prints "is digit" or "is dollar" after the character was to check what had gone wrong in the code and see why the passwords were all valid. I have no idea why all those random characters are printed and I would rather know what is going wrong with my program rather than taking a new approach to the task at hand.

Comment: Ok, so i fixed that part of the code (thank you by the way) but that only partially fixed it. It doesn't always print valid, as long as there is an upper case character and a digit. If the password is 1A then it is valid, 1a is invalid. The random list of weird characters is still present so maybe it has something to do with the variable i and its use in detecting the '$' character in the for loop.

Comment: Look at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) page: you should use the return value of scanf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop is wrong:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 16; i++){
```

If you only type 4 characters, you should only be checking the first 4 characters of the string. This is why you're seeing lots of random characters -- those are the garbage that's in the remaining elements of `password`. It should be:

```
size_t pw_len = strlen(password);
for (i = 0; i < pw_len; i++) {
```

Also, remember that since arrays are zero-based, the last element of the array has the index length-1. So if you do want to process all the elements of an array declared `password[16]`, the loop criteria should be `i < 16`, not `i <= 16` -- that will try to access outside the array on the last iteration.

You also need to initialize the `upper`, `digit`, and `dollar` variables at the beginning of the `while` loop. Otherwise, if you type a password with numbers and `$`, then a new password with uppers, the second password will be called valid because it still has the `digit` and `dollar` settings from the previous password.

So it should be:

```
while(loop == 1){
    upper = digit = dollar = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks that helped, the random characters are not being displayed anymore. The issue now is that it prints valid in the case with a '$' character and a number only rather than a '$' character, a number, and an upper case character.

Comment: You need to reset the `upper`, `digit`, and `dollar` variables each time through the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! The program is now fixed, i really appreciate the help, Barmar.